# My Toyota Corolla 2007 vibrates when idling, stopping at a stop sign. No issue when car is running

Tags: toyota, corolla, vibration

My Toyota Corolla 2007 CE, vibrates when idling or when stopped. The vibration goes away when the car is running. The vibration is coming from the engine. What could be the issue?

I recently changed the serpentine belt and valve cover gasket.

Comment: Have you checked the compressions? A rough idle can be caused by cylinders poorly contributing.

Comment: So you say you changed the belt and the valve cover gasket.  Did these symptoms start after that or were you trying to resolve this issue with those repairs?

Comment: Does this vibration happen in park and neutral, or just in gear?

Comment: Some engines have ECM controlled hydraulic motor mounts and when these go bad cause this symptom. If it does not have this type, a worn out regular engine mount can do the same.

Comment: @jwh20 Yes, the vibration started after chaining the belt and valve cover gasket.

Comment: @GdD Yes, the car vibrates in park, in neutral, and in gear. The vibration goes away once I start driving. Thanks.

Comment: In that case go back and double-check your work.  I doubt it's the belt, provided it installed properly, but you generally need to remove quite a bit of stuff to get at the valve cover gasket.  I'll bet you have neglected to properly reconnect a hose or connector.